# Create dynamic menu in .NET MAUI based on class describing menu items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, maui

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a dynamic menu in .NET MAUI with XAML or programmatically.
In the viewmodel I have declared an observable collection of elements like this:

```cs
public class MyMenuItem
{
    public string MyMenuItemName { get; set; }
    public MyMenuItem[] ChildMenuItems { get; set; }
    public ICommand MyMenuItemCommand { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to know if I can use this collection to generate a menu bar with its subitems etc., (vertical or horizontal) in .NET MAUI.

I've tried to do it programmatically, but I haven't figured out a solution yet.

EDIT:
i've done this way to create the menu programmatically:

```
public void GenerateMenuBar()
{
    var viewModel = (HomePageViewModel)BindingContext;
    AddMenuItemsToMenuBar(viewModel.MenuItems);
}

private void AddMenuItemsToMenuBar(IEnumerable<MyMenuItem> menuItems, IElement parent = null)
{
    foreach (var menuItem in menuItems)
    {
        IElement currentMenuItem;

        if (parent is MenuFlyoutSubItem)
        {
            var parentElement = parent as MenuFlyoutSubItem;
            currentMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem {Text = menuItem.MyMenuItemName, Parent = parentElement};
            parentElement.Add((MenuFlyoutItem)currentMenuItem);
        }
        else if (parent is MenuBarItem && menuItem.ChildMenuItems.Length > 0)
        {
            var parentElement = parent as MenuBarItem;
            currentMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutSubItem {Text = menuItem.MyMenuItemName, Parent = parentElement};
            parentElement.Add((MenuFlyoutSubItem)currentMenuItem);
        }
        else if (parent is MenuBarItem && menuItem.ChildMenuItems.Length == 0)
        {
            var parentElement = parent as MenuBarItem;
            currentMenuItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = menuItem.MyMenuItemName, Parent = parentElement };
            parentElement.Add((MenuFlyoutItem)currentMenuItem);
        }
        else
        {
            currentMenuItem = new MenuBarItem {Text = menuItem.MyMenuItemName};
            this.MenuBarItems.Add((MenuBarItem)currentMenuItem);
        }

        if (menuItem.ChildMenuItems != null)
            AddMenuItemsToMenuBar(menuItem.ChildMenuItems, currentMenuItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this using an [HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyMenuItemCommand}" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildMenuItems}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyMenuItemName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

Comment: it's working very well in WPF, thanks, do you know if something similar can be done in MAUI with the <ContentPage.MenuBarItems> element?

Comment: No. You explicitly create `MenuBarItems` and add them to the `MenuBarItems` collection of a `ContentPage` in MAUI so there is no need for your `MyMenuItem` class there.